# xcode simulator works on iPad button images disappear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have my app working on the simulator just fine but when I install it on a iPad my 2 sets of buttons the button images disappear, here is the code,

```
-(IBAction)ButtonNot1:(id)sender{
UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_Not_At_all_R.png"];
[sender setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Unsure.png"];
UIImage *btnImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Definitely.png"];

UIButton* ButtonUn1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
UIButton* ButtonDef1 = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:3];

[ButtonUn1 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ButtonDef1 setImage:btnImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
sResults1 = @"1";
}
```

So btnImage2 and 3 just show blank buttons no images when you select the first button, this works fine in the simulator

Comment: check case sensitive of image name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was the case sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check  case sensitive  of image name which you're using to refer to the resources. iPhone is case sensitive, but simulator is not case sensitive.